# Generating sequence skipping by 2 Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query.But I want to tweak the output to skip 2 consecutive numbers on every cycle.
For example skip 1,2 in 2nd cycle . Skip 3,4 in 3rd cycle . Skip 5,6 in 4th cycle and so on.

Also, there will be 2 input variables (i) the number to be removed/added (ii) from which date.
Once this is passed the sequence will have to be recalculate from that date on wards.
I am using Oracle version 12.1

```sql
 SELECT TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y') + level - 1 AS "date", MOD(level - 1, 10) + 1 AS col1
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y'), 12) - TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y')
```

```
    Date     Col1  Expected Output
    1/1/2022    1   1
    1/2/2022    2   2
    1/3/2022    3   3
    1/4/2022    4   4
    1/5/2022    5   5
    1/6/2022    6   6
    1/7/2022    7   7
    1/8/2022    8   8
    1/9/2022    9   9
    1/10/2022   10  10 
    1/11/2022   1   3
    1/12/2022   2   4
    1/13/2022   3   5
    1/14/2022   4   6
    1/15/2022   5   7
    1/16/2022   6   8
    1/17/2022   7   9
    1/18/2022   8   10
    1/19/2022   9   1
    1/20/2022   10  2
    1/21/2022   1   5
    1/22/2022   2   6
    1/23/2022   3   7
    1/24/2022   4   8
    1/25/2022   5   9
    1/26/2022   6   10
    1/27/2022   7   1
    1/28/2022   8   2
    1/29/2022   9   3
    1/30/2022   10  4
    1/31/2022   1   7
    2/1/2022    2   8
    2/2/2022    3   9
    2/3/2022    4   10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some more arithmetical functions such as **`FLOOR()`** and **`CEIL()`** along with precomputing unmatched values within a subquery, and then filter out by the incremented values upto the currently existing expression's value of

*`ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y'), 12) - TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y')`*

such as

```sql
WITH d AS
(
   SELECT SUM(CASE 
              WHEN MOD(FLOOR((level-.1)/10),6) = CEIL((MOD(level - 1, 10) + 1)/2) 
              THEN 
                   0 
              ELSE 
                   1 
               END) 
              OVER (ORDER BY level) AS rn, 
          ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y'), 12) - TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y') AS day_diff,
          MOD(level - 1, 10) + 1 AS col1, 
          MOD(FLOOR((level-.1)/10),6) AS col2, 
          CEIL((MOD(level - 1, 10) + 1)/2) AS col3
     FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y'), 12) - TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y'))*2
)
SELECT TRUNC(sysdate, 'Y') + rn - 1 AS "date", col1
  FROM d
 WHERE col2 != col3 
   AND rn <= day_diff 
 ORDER BY rn
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=973c24ffb60c6472ef383723c72091ef)</kbd>

Comment: Thank You so much Barbaros for your prompt help. I will try to plug in the date & number bind variable. Will do some testing with different combinations and dates and see if it works. Thanks once again for the wonderful query!

Comment: I was so eager to write one myself: I posted answer to my question. Please check,if you have time

Comment: if I replace 10 with 5 then I am not getting the correct output.. For 1/16/2022 , I believe it should be 2.My query gives 2 for 1/16/2022. Replace 10 by 5 and 8 by 3 ( 5-2) in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote below . Thanks for your answer as well. I just made some columns in excel and wrote some functions to get it

```sql
WITH Y AS
 (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Y') + LEVEL - 1 dt,
         MOD(LEVEL - 1, 10) + 1 AS grpid,
         LEVEL rnum
    FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
             ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Y'), 12) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Y')),
Z AS
 (SELECT dt,
         rnum,
         COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN grpid = 1 THEN
                  1
               END) OVER(ORDER BY dt) - 1 as grp
    FROM y)

SELECT z.*,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(CASE
                        WHEN MOD(rnum, grp * 10) = 1 THEN
                         MOD(grp + grp + 1, 10)
                        WHEN MOD(rnum, grp * 10) = 2 THEN
                         MOD(grp + grp + 2, 10)
                        ELSE
                         MOD(rnum - grp * (10 - 2), 10)
                      END,
                      '^0$',
                      10) output
  FROM Z;
```

Comment: Replace 10 with any other number to get desired output

Comment: this query is nice as well

Comment: @barbaros-Özhan I tried couple of changes but Not able to set dynamic skip value.. It can be either 1,2 or 3